# Why are these two caracterisations of a meagre set equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

In different courses, I have the following two caracterisations of a meagre set:

(1) A is meagre iff $A=\cup_{d=1}^{\infty} N_d$ where $N_d$ are nowhere-dense sets.

(2) A is meagre iff $A^C \subseteq \cap U_i$ where the $U_i$ are open and dense.

Now I'm frustrated I can't figure this out myself but I can't prove that they are equivalent?

And while I'm at it, if someone also knows how to show that $\cap_n \cup_k ] q_k-2^{-k-n};q_k+2^{-k-n}[$ , -where $q_k$ is an enumeration of the rationals-, is meagre I would be thankful too!

Comment: The set you mention at the end is **not** meagre, it is the complement of a meagre set,  and a second category set. It's the intersection of countably many open dense sets (so Baire applies). It's constructed this way to make it Lebesgue measure $0$. So in measure it's small but topologically it's big.

Comment: In item (2), $\subseteq$ should be $\supseteq$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

1. $N_d$ nowhere dense iff $X\setminus cl(A) $ is dense in $X$
2. Complement of a closed set is open in $(X, d) $
3. Closure of any set is closed.
4. Use De'Morgan's law.